# Matching rows between columns and creating a new column if rows match in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

If I have the following dataframe (df)

```
emp_id  email_ad                    full_nm             mgr_emp_id
65391   Pierric.Beckert@email.com   Pierric Beckert     57834
65392   Mat.Yokoyama@email.com      Mat Yokoyama        92499
65393   Kevin.Harvey@email.com      Kevin Harvey        45325
```

For every row in `mgr_emp_id`, if the `mgr_emp_id` matches with an employee id in `emp_id` then create a new column called `Manager_Name` by getting the name from the `full_nm` column.

I tried the following but I'm not sure how to call the function

```
def mgr1(row):
    for row in df['mgr_emp_id']:
        if row['mgr_emp_id'] == row['emp_id']:
            df['Manager Name']=row['full_nm']
```

I tried calling it this way :

```
df.apply(lambda row: mgr1(row),axis=1)
```

But I received an error :

**TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable**

If there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do please any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You should use `map` or `merge`

Comment: could you please show me how I would do that?

Comment: `df['Manager_Name'] = df['mgr_emp_id'].map(df.set_index('emp_id')['full_nm'])`

Comment: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Do you have duplicated `emp_id`? If so, do they contain the same information?

Comment: the mgr_emp_id column should have values that match to the emp_id column but there is no other duplicated column

Comment: can you post the complete error message?

Comment: I'm not talking about duplicated column. I'm asking for duplicates *within* `emp_id`

Comment: I agree with Quang Hoang. What is the output of `len(df.emp_id), len(df.emp_id.drop_duplicates())`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your wish to "create a new column" for each instance of matching ids is confused. Presumably what you want is an additional column called "Manage Name", and if `emp_id` matches `mgr_emp_id` you want the `full_nm` to equal the "Manage Name". Obviously where there is inequality, you will not know the Manage Name.

To achieve this, you could simply create a new column of NAN values, filter for rows where `emp_id` matches `mgr_emp_id`, and replace the NAN value with that row's `full_nm` value, for those rows.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [65391, 'Pierric.Beckert@email.com', 'Pierric Beckert', 57834],
    [65392, 'Mat.Yokoyama@email.com', 'Mat Yokoyama', 92499],
    [65393, 'Kevin.Harvey@email.com', 'Kevin Harvey', 45325],
    [11111, 'example.same@email.com', 'Example Same', 11111]],
    columns=['emp_id', 'email_ad', 'full_nm', 'mgr_emp_id'])

df['manager_name'] = np.nan

df.loc[df.emp_id.eq(df.mgr_emp_id), 'manager_name'] = df.full_nm
```

In the final line we use `loc` to find the rows where `emp_id` matches `mgr_emp_id`, and the column of interest ("manager_name"), and input the value into that dataframe element, replacing the NAN.

The result is:

```
    emp_id  email_ad                    full_nm         mgr_emp_id  manager_name
0   65391   Pierric.Beckert@email.com   Pierric Beckert 57834       NaN
1   65392   Mat.Yokoyama@email.com      Mat Yokoyama    92499       NaN
2   65393   Kevin.Harvey@email.com      Kevin Harvey    45325       NaN
3   11111   example.same@email.com      Example Same    11111       Example Same
```

If you want to do anything different, I imagine you would want either seperate dataframes or a differently shaped dataframe.